# tcl flattens 3rd level of list, w/o explanation

Tags: list, nested, tcl

See code below:

```
set k [list]
foreach i [list 1 2] {
    lappend k [ list "hey" [ list "ho" [ list $i ] ] ]
}
puts [ join $k ",and,"]
exit
```

The result is:

```
hey {ho 1},and,hey {ho 2}
```

But I expected the result to look like:

```
hey {ho {1}},and,hey {ho {2}}
```

Any ideas why is that so?
Thanks.

Comment: It appears to happen when the list has only a single element.  e.g. `list $i $i` works as you would expect. Hopefully Donal will be able to answer this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone of the `list` command's arguments are more than elements one, then only that corresponding indexed element's return value will have the braced list form.

```
% list a b c; # All list args are having only single element
a b c
% list "a" "b" "c"; # Same as above
a b c
% list {a} {b} {c}; # Same again... 
a b c
% list "a b" c d; # Here, 1st arg is having 2 elements. 
{a b} c d
%
```

Tcl's [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/440) page already mentioned about bizarre behavior of  the nested lists in only one case, which is

```
% list [list [list x]]
x
```

It means that `Tcl` lists alone cannot be used to represent ALL kinds of data structures, as `Tcl` lists magically collapse when it's a series of nested lists with the terminal list having only a single bare word that requires no escaping.

**Update :**

More importantly, if the arg is having a space in it,

```
% list "x "
{x }
% list "x"
x
%
```

Since the space has to be considered as well, `Tcl` has no other way, but to enclose the braces.

Comment: Note that even though the representation looks like the list has been collapsed you can still do: `lset k 1 1 0 d` to change the 3rd nested element.  So it is a matter of how you use your list structure and not so much how it appears.

Comment: @BradLanam, please consider adding this as an answer. You last sentence is key.

Comment: Fun thing: list elements ending with ``\``